# Obter o tamanho de uma div em pixels

Tags: php, html, div, pixels

Eu quero fazer um grid de imagens onde elas se encaixam.
Eu já tinha feito o grid de divs e queria somente colocar o background de uma imagem, porém quando tento as imagens ficam erradas.
Como eu faço para obter o valor em pixel de cada div?

```
<!-- GRID DE CATEGORIA -->
<section class="vc_section categories-section vc_custom_1592415464709 vc_section-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_new_5eea546b9dc7d">
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="false" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1519888573271 et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48efcc mpc-row">



<div class="category-1 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_left-to-right left-to-right wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 vc_col-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef92 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-915f1adcc640451"><!-- MUDAR FUNDO AQUI CATEGORIA 1 -->
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519802774236" style="background:url(branco.png) center no-repeat !important;">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid vc_row-o-content-middle vc_row-flex et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef41 mpc-row">
                <div class="dashed-border wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-345f1adcc640332" >
                    <div class="vc_column-inner">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 36px;color: #ffffff;line-height: 36px;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading capitalize vc_custom_1594131769982">
                                <a href="https://makobaby.com.br/categoria/enxoval/">Enxoval</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="category-3 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_zoomIn zoomIn wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-5 vc_col-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef92 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-195f1adcc640c0a">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519802796319" style="background:url(vermelho.png) center no-repeat !important;"><!-- MUDAR FUNDO AQUI CATEGORIA 4 -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef41 mpc-row">
                <div class="dashed-border wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-655f1adcc640afa">
                    <div class="vc_column-inner">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 36px;color: #ffffff;line-height: 36px;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading capitalize vc_custom_1594131812786">
                                <a href="https://makobaby.com.br/categoria/conjuntos/">Conjuntos</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="category-4 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_right-to-left right-to-left wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 vc_col-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef92 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-825f1adcc6413ec">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519802786702" ><!-- MUDAR FUNDO AQUI CATEGORIA 4 -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef41 mpc-row">
                <div class="dashed-border wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-185f1adcc6412bc">
                    <div class="vc_column-inner">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 36px;color: #ffffff;line-height: 36px;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading capitalize vc_custom_1594131844787">
                                <a href="https://makobaby.com.br/categoria/portas-bebe/">Porta Beb&ecirc;</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</div>
<div class="vc_row-full-width vc_clearfix"></div>
<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="false" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid categories-section vc_custom_1519888580946 et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48efcc mpc-row">



<div class="category-2 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_zoomInLeft zoomInLeft wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 vc_col-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef92 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-415f1adcc641f85">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519802838956" style="background:url(rosa.png) center no-repeat !important;"><!-- MUDAR FUNDO AQUI CATEGORIA 5 -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef41 mpc-row">
                <div class="dashed-border wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-845f1adcc641e63">
                    <div class="vc_column-inner">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 36px;color: #ffffff;line-height: 36px;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading capitalize vc_custom_1594131869278">
                                <a href="https://makobaby.com.br/categoria/babete/">Conjuntos</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="category-5 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_fadeInUp fadeInUp wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 vc_col-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef92 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-775f1adcc642762">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519802824469" style="background:url(cinza.png) center no-repeat !important;" ><!-- MUDAR FUNDO AQUI CATEGORIA 5 -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef41 mpc-row">
                <div class="dashed-border wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-185f1adcc64264b">
                    <div class="vc_column-inner">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 36px;color: #ffffff;line-height: 36px;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading capitalize vc_custom_1594131936130">
                                <a href="https://makobaby.com.br/categoria/enxoval/mantas/">Mantas</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="category-6 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_zoomInRight zoomInRight wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 vc_col-has-fill et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef92 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-295f1adcc642f0c">
    <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519802846321"><!-- MUDAR FUNDO AQUI CATEGORIA 6 -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid et_custom_uniqid_5f1adcc48ef41 mpc-row">
                <div class="dashed-border wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12 mpc-column" data-column-id="mpc_column-765f1adcc642df4">
                    <div class="vc_column-inner">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 36px;color: #ffffff;line-height: 36px;text-align: center" class="vc_custom_heading capitalize vc_custom_1594131959873">
                                <a href="https://makobaby.com.br/categoria/enxoval/toalha/">Toalha</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div><div class="vc_row-full-width vc_clearfix"></div></section>
```

Este é meu código do grid, eu queria pegar o tamanho de pixels exato ou aproximado de cada uma, seria possível?

Comment: Errado como? O que está errado no grid?

Comment: O grid nada, porém na hora de colocar uma foto, os encaixe não ficam perfeitos, já tentei diversos tamanhos e nada, então eu só queria saber o tamanho dessa div correta, para por um background em imagem, isto usando center, no repeat e diversas coisas

Comment: Já tentou com `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: Cheguei a conseguir, porém esse 1 deu problema, isso deve ser em relação ao tamanho da imagem

print: https://prnt.sc/tpc11b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou responder a sua pergunta, mas realmente não sei se ela vai resolver o seu problema...

Vc pode usar o método `.getBoundingClientRect()` e pega a altura e largura do elemento. Vc pode ler uma documentação sobre isso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Repare que no `console` vai retornar o `width` e `height` da `div`, mais `2px` referentes ao `border` ;)

```js
let el = document.getElementById("meuElemento").getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('largura: ' + el.width, 'altura: ' + el.height);
```

```css
#meuElemento {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="meuElemento">123</div>
```

Comment: Fala que o valor é vazio, mesmo eu dando uma pesquisada para ver se pegar o valor do ClassName, deu o mesmo problema

Comment: @ChristianoBourguignon É pq talvez vc tenha que usar um .forEach() para pegar os .querySelectorAll()  depende da forma que vc está fazendo no seu JS, mas ai é uma outra dúvida e te recomendo abrir outra pergunta...

Comment: Teria como entrar no meu site e conseguir obter o valor por lá, uma coisa que descobri é que o width é 1004 px

Comment: @ChristianoBourguignon tem sim, entra no seu site abre o Console do DevTools e roda o Script por ali

Comment: Perfeito, vou tentar

Comment: O mais estranho é que quando digito, display fica none

Comment: Não apareceu nada no console ainda

Comment: Pode testar? site em questão é o makobaby.com.br

Comment: @ChristianoBourguignon https://prnt.sc/tqmwh5